# Помогите определить источник нагрузки. PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, нагрузка

Всем привет.
Имеем достаточно мощный сервер 2xXeon Gold 5218R 2.10GHz 256DDR4, обслуживающий всего один сайт на php+mysql.
В базе Mysql (innodb) имеется таблица items в 23 поля, основная работа происходит с ней - множество операций insert, множество операций чтения, раз в 3 часа - очистка ненужных записей. Для таблицы установлено 6 индексов + primary key. Все запросы происходят исключительно по ключам, основные - по полю

> `uid` VARCHAR(32)

которое так же является индексом.

Принцип работы: пользователи добавляют в таблицу items записи, затем запускается долгий скрипт PHP, который в цикле выбирает записи по `uid` и обрабатывает их.
Этот скрипт - "бесконечный" цикл while. Он выбирает записи по uid+id пользователя+status (обработано или нет), обрабатывает, затем снова выбирает и обрабатывает - так до тех пор, пока записи существуют)
В среднем пользователь добавляет по 300-500 записей, их обработка занимает 10-30 минут. В таблице постоянно имеется ~2млн записей, уникальных `uid` - порядка 20 тысяч.
В данном режиме сервер работает относительно "спокойно" - потребление CPU на уровне 1-2%, быстрый отклик и т.д.

Кроме того, каждый час cron запускает аналогичные скрипты, которые в автоматическом режиме запускают такие же циклы обработки. Одновременно запускается от 500 до 1000 заданий (выбираются по условию из другой таблицы и в цикле exec ('/usr/bin/php ...'); запускаются). В такие моменты нагрузка на сервер заметно возрастает. Причем возрастает в разы, load average достигает 200 и выше, сайт становится недоступен. Такая нагрузка наблюдается 20-30 минут, затем постепенно спадает, затем (в очередной час) - снова скачет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оптимизацией занимаюсь последних пару недель. За это время сделано -

- mysql сконфигурирован, пожалуй, насколько это возможно
- по некоторым рекомендациям в бесконечные циклы добавлено sleep(1), и кажется это помогло немного снизить нагрузку
- оптимизирован php-код, проверены все запросы с explain
- INSERT, которые раньше в момент пиковой нагрузки занимали до 20 секунд, заменены на LOAD DATA INFILE, но даже сейчас такие запросы порой занимают до 3 секунд.
- Пробовали даже изменять настройку времени по рекомендациям https://blog.bullgare.com/2012/08/mysql-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8/ - не помогло.

Казалось бы, сайт требует действительно больших ресурсов, но до недавнего времени все прекрасно работало на "обычном" 4 ядерном сервере с 32Gb памяти, а сейчас многократно увеличив ресурс, без изменения в скриптах - получил странную производительность.

Надеюсь, здесь найдутся специалисты, которые подскажут над чем еще стоит поработать.

Comment: а эту выборку по ид и статус, обраотку и обновлени нельзя из пхп в mysql перенести? И основное - если затупы у вас когда запускаете 500-1000 процессов, то может не стоит так делать? запускайте пачками по 50 по очереди.

Comment: Процессы запускаются по расписанию пользователей. Если запускать их пачками, то задание например вместо настроенного времени выполнения 09:00 - может выполниться только в 12:00 или позднее

Comment: то есть условная пачка в 50 задач будет выполняться 3 часа, а если  разом 1000 запустить, то прям моментально выполнятся в 09:00 ? В чем если не секрет состояит обработка записей пользователей по 30-50 минут? видео что ли конвертите какое-то? Специфику процесса хоть поясните, мб понятнеее кому-нибудь станет. А то сейчас не ясно, 30 минут потому что задача реально бльшая, или 30 минут потому что у вас там запросы к БД в цикле друг за другом в цикле сыпятся кучей на каждой итерации.

Comment: Специфика - скачивание и выгрузка фото. В цикле допустим качается 100-500 фото, и тут же выгружается, между выгрузками - пауза, поэтому процессы занимают порой много времени. Из 1000 часть завершится в течении минуты, там фото будет не так много.

Comment: Важен запуск задания в установленное пользователем время. То, что они запускаются разом (сам процесс запуска) нагрузки не создаёт, нагрузка именно от их выполнения. Если запускать порциями по 50шт ради паузы между запуском - то время выполнения существенно сместится. Если запускать просто порциями по 50 без паузы - уверен, разницы не будет. Сам запуск происходит практически моментально

Comment: ну естественно речь шла не о том, чтобы запускать порциями без паузы, а о том, чтобы ограничить число процессов. То есть условно не для каждого из N пользователей запускать свой процесс, а ограничить число процессов каким то опытно-подобранным, условно 100, и чтобы в сумме они обработали все те же данные для N пользователей. То ест один процесс будет решать задачу не одного пользователя, а нескольких. Вообще условно разделить все фото которые надо скопировать на 100, и распределить их между 100 процессами, отсортировав как-нибудь, чтобы за мин. время были охвачены все пользователи.

Comment: Хм. Подумаю, возможно ли так сделать. Дело в том, что отдельный процесс работает для отдельного пользователя - ведет загрузку, пишет статистику и т.д., и одна из настроек процесса - это скорость его выполнения. Если в один процесс скормить задачи, например, 50 пользователей - то соответственно возрастет и время выполнения, и статистику и т.д. придется разделять.. Но посыл понятен, подумаю над реализацией